# How to bevel inside like Mario's coin

Tags: bevel

I want to make Mario's coin. Now, I made it here so far.

[image]

I don't know how to bevel inside, like reference image.

[image]

Someone can help? Thank you.

Comment: Did you have a look at the `Bevel` modifier?

Comment: Select the edges -> ctrl+b

Comment: Dear Ailurus - Thank you for your comment. Yes, I had look Bevel modifier. I solved this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Dear Reaper - Oh, that's very easy. Thank you very much for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Plane and make it rectangular shape scaling in x axis

Apply scale <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> -> Scale

Select the plane in Edit mode -> Select the 4 verts and Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to Bevel

Select all and press <kbd>E</kbd> to Extrude

Select all and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>N</kbd> to normal faces

Select the circle and Add a Edge Modifier & a Boolean Modifier with the target of plane

Add Bevel Modifier

Watch this [preview](http://pasteall.org/pic/index.php?id=120257)

Comment: What's so difficult adding `<kbd>KEY</kbd>` to your shortcuts as Ray suggested a million times?

Comment: Not everyone knows about it. I discovered it quite by accident. (:

Comment: Maybe a moderator or someone with higher rep could edit?